# How to cancel pending changes in NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: ios

In my code, I inserted on entity with:

```
customer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Customer" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Then if I inspect details of self.managedObjectContext, I can see one record under self.managedObjectContext -> unprocessedInserts

But in some cases(e.g: user pressed the cancel button), I want to cancel this pending change, could you please tell me how to make this happen? I do not want to alloc and init a new managedObjectContext.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with rollback:

```
- (void) rollback
```

> Removes everything from the undo stack, discards all insertions and
>   deletions, and    restores updated objects to their last committed
>   values.

Read the apple docs for more detailed information: [Rollback](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-BAJEJBGH)